# Showing model data as dropdown list in html Template in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to access model's data for implementation as dropdown menu but I got stuck in this problem. Can anyone help me??
Here is what i have....

**views.py**

```
    def educationdata(request):
        obj = DegreeDetails.objects.all()
        context={
            'Data':obj
        }
        return render(request,'Education.html', context)
```

This the view I have created for the model DegreeDetails

**Model.py**

```
    class DegreeDetails (models.Model):
        degree = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        discipline = models.CharField(max_length= 15)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s'%(self.degree, self.discipline)
```

This is the model i am using and this model is used as a ForeignKey in another model as follows, hence i want to show it as dropdown field

```
    degree_details = models.ForeignKey(DegreeDetails, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

**Template.Html**

```
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                          <label>Degree Details</label>
                          <input type="text" name="degree_details" id="inputdegree_details" class="form-control" placeholder="Select from Dropdown" value="{{education_form.initial.degree_details}}">
                          <select class="form-control">
                          {% for data in Data %}  
                            <option>{{data}}</option>
                          {% endfor %}
                        </select>
```

Look forward to your responses, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use django forms. It is well explained in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Django Forms or modelforms.

Official Document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

**for fixing the current code that you have written.**

you need to set id as a value for each option in the dropdown.

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                      <label>Degree Details</label>
                      <input type="text" name="degree_details" id="inputdegree_details" class="form-control" placeholder="Select from Dropdown" value="{{education_form.initial.degree_details}}">
                      <select class="form-control">
                      {% for data in Data %}  
                        <option value="{{data.id}}">{{data}}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </select>
```